# For/While Loops to make *-triangles

Tags: python, python-3.x

For an assignment in a coding class, I was supposed to find a way to have Python make a triangle of asterisks, looking like this:

```
   x
  xx
 xxx
```

Whatever I do with my code, however, I can't manage to pull that off. The best I 
can get is:

```
x
xx
xxx
```

All of this has to be using only for-loops and while-loops, like what I'm using here. The code I'm using is

```
for a in range(1, 15):
 for a2 in range(14-a, 0, 1):
     print(" ", end='')
 for a1 in range(1, a+ 1):
     print("*", end='')
 print()
```

The -'s are there to represent indent. How do I make this work the way I want it to?

Edit: Turns out, I only noticed half of my problem. The code I wound up using, here, makes the two triangles I need, but stacks them one below the other. What I'm having trouble with now is making them appear side-by-side, like an M shape.

```
for b in range(1, 10):
    for b2 in range(9-b, 0, 1):
        print(" ", end='')    
    for b1 in range(1, b+ 1):
        print("*", end='')
    print()

for a in range(1, 10):
    for a2 in range(9-a, 0, -1):
        print(" ", end='')
    for a1 in range(1, a+ 1):
        print("*", end='')
    print()
```

I know I'm missing something, I just can't see what it is.

Comment: You can do it all in two lines if you use `{:<N}` and `{:>N}` with `format`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to solve both problems using only for loops. This approach is not very pythonic, but this is what you requested.

### Solution for single triangle problem

```
   x
  xx
 xxx
```

You were really close. You wrote `1` instead of `-1` when you wanted to go down from 14-a to 0.

```
for a in range(1, 15):
 for a2 in range(14-a, 0, -1):
     print(" ", end='')
 for a1 in range(1, a+ 1):
     print("*", end='')
 print()
```

Explanation (from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)):

> range(start, stop[, step])
>
> > If the step argument is omitted, it
> >     defaults to 1. If step is positive, the last element is the largest
> >     start + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element
> >     is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop.

So in your case, your original for loop did nothing because *14-a* was not smaller than *0* and *step* was positive .

### Solution for M shape problem

```
 x    x
 xx  xx
 xxxxxx
```

-

```
HEIGHT = 3
for b in range(1, HEIGHT+1):
    for a in range(1, b + 1):
        print("*", end='')
    for a in range(0, 2*(HEIGHT-b)):
        print(" ", end='')
    for a in range(1, b + 1):
        print("*", end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

- `"{0}+++{0}".format('Hello!')` produces two copies of the zeroth argument to `format` (here `'Hello!'`), separated by three plusses: `Hello!+++Hello!`.
- `"{:<4}".format('x')` left-justifies `'x'` in a 4-character field; i.e., `'x   '`.
- `"{:>4}".format('x')` right-justifies `'x'` in a 4-character field; i.e., `'   x'`.
- `"{:>{}}".format('x', width)` right-justifies `'x'` in a `width`-character field.
- `'ab' * 4` yields 4 copies of `'ab'`; i.e., `'abababab'`.

Putting them together:

```
>>> WIDTH = 4
>>>
>>> for a in range(1, WIDTH+1):
...     print("{0:<{1}}{0:>{1}}".format('*' * a, WIDTH))
...
*      *
**    **
***  ***
********
```

Handy references: [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/) and [Python String Format Cookbook](https://mkaz.tech/python-string-format.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another option to avoid multiple for loops is to use the multiplication operator with the string. `"*" * 3 = "***"`

```
for a in range(1, 15):
    print(" " * (14-a), end = '')
    print("*" * a)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a list comprehension:

```
>>> count_tuples = zip(range(2,-1,-1), range(1,4))
>>> stars = ['%s%s' % (space * ' ', star * '*') for space, star in count_tuples]
>>> print("\n".join(stars))
  *
 **
***
```

That's equivalent to the following solution:

```
>>> for space, star in zip(range(2,-1,-1), range(1,4)):
...     print '%s%s' % (space * ' ', star * '*')
  *
 **
***
```

Answer (score 0):

Using most basic commands:

```
for i in range(8, 0, -1):
    print(i * ' ', '%')
```

Output:

```
         %
        %
       %
      %
     %
    %
   %
  %
```